# Maximize the number of lines that end in a certain character

Tags: algorithm

You are given a line of strings, each words are seperated by spaces. You can only insert new lines in the 5-10th column of your string. Your goal is to maximize the number of lines that end with the character `x`. How would you do this for example.

Edit: The words can end with any character, Say you are given the text

```
abcdfg cdx abcdx abcdefg aa ggffx ax
```

then the way to display them would be

```
column:
1234567890
abcdfg cdx
abcdx
abcdefg 
aa ggfx
ax
```

this would maximize the result because it has 4 lines that end with `x`

I feel the real problem of this question is how do we break if it doesn't end with `x` and it is at a position that can break.

Observe

```
abcdefg 
aa ggfx
ax
```

If aa was on the 1st line with abcdefg then we will only be able to have 1 more line of `x` because `ggfx` can't break right away. As a result `ggfx ax` would be on the same line

Comment: There is a pool of water on the ground. The door is locked from the inside. Two guards wait outside. One always lies. Both speak in an unknown language. The cake is a lie.

Comment: Define your data set here.  Is it one long string that has a bunch of words that might or might not end in x?  What are you considering a column? Character Column (where space counts as a character too) or is each "word" a column?

Comment: How are you breaking twice in your example? the break at the end of `abcdx` is outside the index you defined.

Comment: @Graphain: he did say 5-10, and 'abcdx' is five long...

Comment: @Borealid only if we restart the count.

Answer (score 1):

Break the line every time you *can* break the line and encounter the appropriate character.  If there is no target character within the next nine, break all the time.

This will give an optimal answer, unfortunately.  It's a simple game.

It would be more interesting if we could score for lines that had the target character in some range of columns (say, in columns 8-10).  But with only the last column counting, greedy wins the day.

I'm assuming here you are allowed to chop words up without having to hyphenate or anything.  But you didn't give us other rules, so what other assumption could I make?

```
String str = "000x0dfkdfjfxxiwrhx fsjhfx fwuhxjhfe xj etc etc you get it";
int doneidx = 0;
char targetchar = 'x';
StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
while (doneidx < str.length()) {
    if (tmp.length() < 5) {
        tmp.append(str.charAt(doneidx));
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (doneidx+i < str.length() && str.charAt(doneidx+i) == targetchar) {
                tmp.append(str.substring(doneidx, doneidx+i+1)); 
                doneidx += i+1;
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(tmp.toString());
        tmp = new StringBuffer();
    }
}
```

This is an O(N^2) algorithm.  It could be reduced to O(N) using memoization.  But, honestly, I don't think it matters here.

Comment: You are not allowed to brake words up. For some reason I dont think it's that simple. If as soon as we encounter a word that's breakable and ends with x then we brake, will this cause a lower scores for the words in the future? Im thinking more of dynamic rather than greedy.

Comment: @tomwu: aargh, why didn't you say that?  Now I have to go rewrite my working code solution -_-.

Answer (score 0):

I would naively try something like the following pseudocode:

```
string foo = "abcdfg cdx abcdx ggx"; 
string newFoo = foo; /* Assumes immutable strings */

int startIndex = 5; 
int endIndex = 10; 
int inserts = 0;

for (int i=startIndex-1; i<=endIndex-1 && i<foo.Length-1; i++) 
{ 
 if (foo.Substring(i, 1) == "x") /* Substr is (startIn, length) */ 
 { 
    newFoo = newFoo.Insert(i+1+inserts, "\n");
    inserts++;
 } 
}
```

Will leave starting spaces if next char was a space on the break. Not sure if this is desired.

Comment: That's ... not right.  You can't break the line at i and i+1 at the same time.  You need to increment i by five each time you insert a break.

Comment: How am I breaking it as i and i+1? Why would I increment by five each time I insert a break?

Comment: In addition if we are already in the 5-10 range, and the current word do not end with x, we also have to brake even if it doesnt end with x

Comment: So, let's say you have 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx' as your string.  What happens with your code?

Comment: @Borealid you get: xxxxx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nx\nxxxx. @tomwu that contradicts what you just told borealid (you can't break whenever you want).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear, Assume the word will always be smaller than the max column(10 this case)

Comment: @tomwu why do you want to break if the word is smaller than the max?

Comment: I'm done editing this answer, the specs are ridiculously vague, little attempt appears to have been made by the OP to answer this themself (or they would have a better understood spec) and the specs keep changing.

Comment: @Graphain I am saying the individual words used will alway be smaller than 10. You are not allowed to brake up an individual word

Comment: @tomwu: Just saying that all words are smaller than ten is **not** sufficient to prevent an impossible situation.  I'm done here.